Нужна ли запятая после «убить»?
То, что можно убить(,) не целясь.

То, что можно убить не целясь.
Запятая перед деепричастием не нужна, так как оно выражает основное содержание предложения.
Деепричастные конструкции (справочник Розенталя):

Примечание. Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется:
1) если деепричастный оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания: Она сидела чуть откинув голову (Марк.) — указывается, что она не просто сидела, а сидела с откинутой головой; Жили Артамоновы ни с кем не знакомясь (М. Г.) — важно, что жили без всяких знакомств.


Это кроссворд.  То что можно убить не целясь — 5 букв.  А что это?

@Sharon  Ответов, вероятно, может быть несколько. Убить можно время :))

Хороший варинт))

А первая запятая точно нужна, как-то она не смотрится?  По аналогии с "то что надо"?  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=то,%20что%20надо&mode=spravka  Несимметричная запись, и паузы там нет.

@Sharon Нужна. Здесь же не тот случай, о котором пишет Грамота: А денек выдался то что надо.   А тот, что дальше: Я рассмотрел ваше предложение – то, что надо было рассмотреть. // Пауза ни при чём, просто грамматика.

Это да,  но, может, для кроссвордов особые правила?  https://poncy.ru/crossword/?mask=-----&desc=то%20что%20можно%20убить%20не%20целясь

@Sharon  Тогда нужен вопрос об особых критериях оформления кроссвордских загадок.

Да, с этим вопросом надо в Справочную службу)
